# cakePHP store pagination parameters and recall on next visit

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am trying to store a state of a paging request. I want users when leaving a page with the cakephp pagination component on (to example edit), on return, be returned to the last page visited with the pagination component.

So if a user visited http://www.site.com/users/view/page:3, and they leave the page, they must be returned to the same page. I tried a pagination recall component I got online but did not manage to get it to work. I am using cakePHP 2.0

Comment: Are you wanting to store it permanently or just during the session. I.e., when they log out and log back in are you wanting to take them to their last paginated page?

Comment: Not permanently, sessions are fine. I have managed to store the sort by with session and can successfully recall that. Is ther any way of setting to the paginator which "page" to display, so in other words, if the url says page:3, but I set the property to page => 4, that it would display page 4? That way I can purely check what the last page was, store that as a session and also recall it when needed.

Comment: Sure, just modify the params on the request object.

Comment: Hey jeremy, I tried to modify the value by doing $this->params["named"]["page"] in my controller but I am getting a "Indirect modification of overloaded element of CakeRequest has no effect"

Comment: Modify the request object, like `$this->request->params['named']['page']`.

Comment: if you want to, submit it as the answer and I'll approve your answer as the working one

Comment: Cool, I submitted an answer. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify what the paginator uses as it's parameters, you'll need to modify the `CakeRequest` object on the controller before calling `$this->Paginator->paginate()`.

For example, if the user browsed to `/users/index/page:3` and you want to send them to page 4 instead, modify the request in the controller like so:

```
$this->request->params['named']['page'] = 4;
```